# Pickable not working with Deck.GL custom Trip Routes layer

Tags: webgl2, deck.gl

I was working on deck.gl trip routes example
http://deck.gl/#/examples/custom-layers/trip-routes

I want to implement pickable functionality in the layers.
On setting `pickable: true` in layer properties and increasing the pickable radius, the results were not the same as expected.

Then I followed https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/docs/get-started/interactivity.md and https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/docs/developer-guide/picking.md to implement custom picking. However, that didn't work.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work, or do you have a code sample?